# convert categorical data into numerical data?

Tags: dataset, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am doing project for post graduation....project is document clustering.in the project raise the problem is the text data convert into the numerical data?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to build the classical Bag of Words features by counting words (and normalizing using eg TF-IDF). Another approach would be using word hashing, perhaps here you would like to use ngrams as more powerful features as well. Some data cleaning might be needed before (do not neglect this step).

When features are extracted, you can try Latent Dirichlet Allocation (see Vowpal Wabbit package for implementation). The LDA algorithm will transform your word documents into topic documents. These new representations are arguably better when trying to cluster the documents (eg using k-means). Here are two important parameters to tune - number of topics and number of clusters.

Comment: TF-IDF use after removing stop words and stemming ...otherwise no need of those..

Comment: i have 20 text documents ...how to cluster those documents?